# Read local psql table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, psql

Currently I was given a table with psql format and would like to load its content in a pandas dataframe. The file looks like this (this is a sample of the real file which has hundreds of rows):

```
       ,----------------------------------------------------------------.
       |                          ./csrnab.hyp                          |
       |----------------------------------------------------------------|
       | SPKR   | # Snt # Wrd | Corr    Sub    Del    Ins    Err  S.Err |
       |--------+-------------+-----------------------------------------|
       | 4t0    |   15    458 | 91.0   46.9    4.7   12.3   63.8   86.7 |
       |--------+-------------+-----------------------------------------|
       | 4t1    |   21    544 | 96.5   24.3    0.8    2.7   27.8   57.1 |
       |--------+-------------+-----------------------------------------|
       | 4t2    |   15    404 | 98.1   34.2    0.3    8.9   43.4   86.7 |
       |================================================================|
       | Sum/Avg|   51   1406 | 95.1   34.9    1.9    7.8   44.6   74.5 |
       |================================================================|
       |  Mean  | 17.0  468.7 | 95.2   35.1    1.9    8.0   45.0   76.8 |
       |  S.D.  |  3.5   70.6 |  3.7   11.3    2.4    4.9   18.1   17.0 |
       | Median | 15.0  458.0 | 96.5   34.2    0.8    8.9   43.4   86.7 |
       `----------------------------------------------------------------'
```

I've been doing some research and found out that such format corresponds to psql. Therefore, I the method `read_sql_table` should be use. After trying this out I got the following:

```
df=pd.read_sql_table("ctm_filt.sys")
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-a024294e52cf> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 
----> 3 df=pd.read_sql_table("ctm_filt.sys")

TypeError: read_sql_table() missing 1 required positional argument: 'con'
```

It seems like the "con" input argument is mandatory, but I have no idea what I should write there since I don't need to get any connection with any database since my file is locally stored.

Comment: This is unrelated to psql except that it could have been produced by that. But this is a Fixed Width Fields file. The best tool to load it into a pandas dataframe is [`read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a case of being systematic.  There are cases of pipe delimited and space delimited

- `read_sql_table()` is not suitable,  it connects to a database
- `read_table() as first pass, skipping header rows and using pipe as delimited
- cleanup the columns

  - strip leading/trailing spaces
  - ensure no embedded spaces in column names to prevent issues with subsequent step
  - drop redundant columns which are artifact of pipe denim
- remove unwanted rows that are the row delimiters
- pass through `read_csv()` with space as delimiter to get wanted DF

```
import io
df1 = pd.read_table(io.StringIO("""       ,----------------------------------------------------------------.
       |                          ./csrnab.hyp                          |
       |----------------------------------------------------------------|
       | SPKR   | # Snt # Wrd | Corr    Sub    Del    Ins    Err  S.Err |
       |--------+-------------+-----------------------------------------|
       | 4t0    |   15    458 | 91.0   46.9    4.7   12.3   63.8   86.7 |
       |--------+-------------+-----------------------------------------|
       | 4t1    |   21    544 | 96.5   24.3    0.8    2.7   27.8   57.1 |
       |--------+-------------+-----------------------------------------|
       | 4t2    |   15    404 | 98.1   34.2    0.3    8.9   43.4   86.7 |
       |================================================================|
       | Sum/Avg|   51   1406 | 95.1   34.9    1.9    7.8   44.6   74.5 |
       |================================================================|
       |  Mean  | 17.0  468.7 | 95.2   35.1    1.9    8.0   45.0   76.8 |
       |  S.D.  |  3.5   70.6 |  3.7   11.3    2.4    4.9   18.1   17.0 |
       | Median | 15.0  458.0 | 96.5   34.2    0.8    8.9   43.4   86.7 |
       `----------------------------------------------------------------'""")
             , skiprows=3, sep="|")

# tidy up columns
df1 = df1.rename(columns={c:c.strip().replace("# ", "#") for c in df1.columns}).drop(columns=["","Unnamed: 4"])
# tidy up rows
df1 = df1.drop(df1[df1.SPKR.str.contains("---") | df1.SPKR.str.contains("===")].index).dropna()
# finally deal with space delims as well
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(df1.to_csv(sep=" ").replace("\"", "")), sep="\s+")
```

#### output

|  | SPKR | #Snt | #Wrd | Corr | Sub | Del | Ins | Err | S.Err |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4t0 | 15 | 458 | 91 | 46.9 | 4.7 | 12.3 | 63.8 | 86.7 |
| 3 | 4t1 | 21 | 544 | 96.5 | 24.3 | 0.8 | 2.7 | 27.8 | 57.1 |
| 5 | 4t2 | 15 | 404 | 98.1 | 34.2 | 0.3 | 8.9 | 43.4 | 86.7 |
| 7 | Sum/Avg | 51 | 1406 | 95.1 | 34.9 | 1.9 | 7.8 | 44.6 | 74.5 |
| 9 | Mean | 17 | 468.7 | 95.2 | 35.1 | 1.9 | 8 | 45 | 76.8 |
| 10 | S.D. | 3.5 | 70.6 | 3.7 | 11.3 | 2.4 | 4.9 | 18.1 | 17 |
| 11 | Median | 15 | 458 | 96.5 | 34.2 | 0.8 | 8.9 | 43.4 | 86.7 |

Comment: The first I have to say is: Thanks a mil! I'm just a newbie with pandas so it'll take some time to digest this solution. But I already tried it out and work beautifully. The only thing problem I see is having the table hard coded there. Isn't it possible to pass the filename to read_table?

Comment: the sample you provided is text.  if you replace parameter to `read_table()` to a filename it will use file contents.  `io.StringIO()` simulates a file from a string. pls accept answer if it works